# Stubbing a promisified function with sinon and bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sinon, bluebird

In the file I would like to test, I have the following code:

```
var httpGet = Promise.promisify(require("request").get);
httpGet(endpoint, {
    auth: {bearer: req.body.access_token},
    json: true
})
    .then(...)
```

Now, in my tests, I want to make sure that httpGet was called once, and make sure the parameters are valid. Before being promisified, my test looked like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    request.get = sinon.stub()
        .yields(null, null, {error: "test error", error_description: "fake google error."});
});

afterEach(function () {
    expect(request.get).to.have.been.calledOnce();
    var requestArgs = request.get.args[0];
    var uri = requestArgs[0];

    expect(uri).to.equal(endpoint);
    //...
});
```

Unfortunately this no longer works when request.get is promisified. I tried stubbing request.getAsync instead (since bluebird appends "Async" to promisified functions), but that does not work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Promise.promisify doesn't modify the object, it simply takes a function and returns a new function, it is completely unaware that the function even belongs to `"request"`.

`"Async"` suffixed methods are added to the object when using promisify **All**

```
Promise.promisifyAll(require("request"));

request.getAsync = sinon.stub()
        .yields(null, null, {error: "test error", error_description: "fake google error."});

expect(request.getAsync).to.have.been.calledOnce();
```

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this, what worked for me is to do `Promise.promisifyAll()` first and then put a stub on the `someMethodAsync()` that you want to override temporarily for a test.

Answer (score 2):

Just for future reference I've solved this a bit differently, and I think a little cleaner. This is typescript, but basically the same thing.

fileBeingTested.ts

```
import * as Bluebird from 'bluebird';
import * as needsPromise from 'needs-promise';

const methodAsync = Bluebird.promisify(needsPromise.method);

export function whatever() {
    methodAsync().then(...).catch(...);
}
```

test.spec.ts

```
import * as needsPromise from 'needs-promise';
import * as sinon form 'sinon';

const methodStub = sinon.stub(needsPromise, method);
import { whatever } from './fileBeingTested';
```

Then you use the `methodStub` to manage what calls happen. You can ignore that it's being promisified and just manage it's normal behavior. for example if you need it to error.

```
methodStub.callsFake((arg, callback) => {
    callback({ error: 'Error' }, []);
});
```

The promisified version will throw the error and you'll get it in the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone coming across this. I have small utility func

```
function stubCBForPromisify(stub) {
  let cbFn = function() {
    let args = [...arguments];
    args.shift();
    return stub(...args);
  };
  return cbFn.bind(cbFn, () => ({}));
}
```

In test

```
var getStub = sinon.stub().yields(null, {error: "test error", error_description: "fake google error."})
sinon.stub(require("request"), 'get', stubCBForPromisify(getStub))
expect(getStub).to.have.been.calledOnce();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into trouble testing this using `tape` and `proxyquire`. I'm not sure what pattern/framework people are using that allowed them to modify the `required`'d `request` object directly as shown in the accepted answer. In my case, in the file I want to test I `require('jsonFile')`, then call `bluebird.promisifyAll(jsonFile)`. Under normal conditions this creates a `readFileAsync` method that I want to stub. However, if during testing I try to use `proxyquire` to pass in a stub, the call to `promisifyAll` overwrites my stub.

I was able to fix this by also stubbing `promisifyAll` to be a no-op. As shown this might be too coarse if you rely on some of the async methods to be created as-is.

`core.js`:

```
var jsonFile = require('jsonfile');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
Promise.promisifyAll(jsonFile);

exports.getFile = function(path) {
  // I want to stub this method during tests. It is
  // created by promisifyAll
  return jsonFile.readFileAsync(path);
}
```

`core-test.js`:

```
var proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
var tape = require('tape');
var sinon = require('sinon');
require('sinon-as-promised');

tape('stub readFileAsync', function(t) {
  var core = proxyquire('./core', {
    'jsonfile': {
      readFileAsync: sinon.stub().resolves({})
    },
    'bluebird': { promisifyAll: function() {} }
  });
  // Now core.getFile() will use my stubbed function, and it
  // won't be overwritten by promisifyAll.
});
```